# how to submit post with id in php

Tags: javascript, php

how to get post id in JavaScript. like Facebook comment style. 
i need all post id after submit comment.
this code only submit single post. 
i am using multi post in one page.

```
$(function() {
    $(".comment_submit_button").click(function() {

        var textcommets = $("#commets").val();
        var dataString = 'commets='+ textcommets;
        if(textcommets=='')
        {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#commets").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comment_action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('commets').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#commets").focus();
                }  
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});

<form  method="post" name="form" action="">
    <textarea style="width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px; font-weight:bold; resize:none;" name="commets" id="commets" ></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="comment_submit_button"/>
</form>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="flash" align="left"  ></div>
<div id="show" align="left"></div>
```

Comment: there's no post ID in your HTML as far as I can see. So it's hard to say how to get the post ID because it doesn't seem to be there. Is this your real code, or just an example? I think you need to make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: it's just example

Comment: right well we can't really help unless you show a better example. We have no idea what this post ID is that you're referring to, or how to retrieve or or use it, because we don't know where you are trying to get that value from.

Comment: P.S. a separate point - you'd be better supplyng your data to `$.ajax` as an object, e.g. `data: { "commets": textcommets }`, otherwise you might run into URL-encoding issues by naively building the querystring manually (as you are doing now), especially if the input contains some unusual characters or something. If you define it as I suggested then jQuery will take care of encoding it properly for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you talk about new post id? Just return this value from server after adding. Like this JSON:

```
{
    "postId":1,
    "html": .....
}
```

Js:

```
var postId = response.postId;
$("#show").after(response.html);
```